# WSO2-wso2am-2.1.0 API manager!!! Failed to start wso2 API Manager

Tags: java, mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

./wso2server.sh

While am running sudo sh wso2server.sh

```
[2018-10-04 09:27:43,575]  INFO - TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2018-10-04 09:27:45,052] ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:401)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:263)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:355)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY for tenant : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:839)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4064)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:280)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:222)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:991)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:827)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.34.wso2v2
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:565)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:973)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.34.wso2v2
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
        ... 38 more
[2018-10-04 09:27:45,060] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:322)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:263)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:401)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:355)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY for tenant : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:839)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4064)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:280)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:222)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:991)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:827)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.34.wso2v2
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:565)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:973)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.34.wso2v2
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
        ... 38 more
[2018-10-04 09:27:55,695]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have configured a MySQL database, but have not copied the MySQL driver jar to the `repository/components/lib/`.

Try that.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response. Issue fixed.

Comment: Hello @Bee Can you please share the doc for WSO2 API and IS configuration of SSL

Comment: For SSL you only have to put https instead of http for all urls.

Comment: Hello @Bee I have purchased SSL from Comodo I need to install it on my wso2 server. If it is possible? then How can I configure the SSL certificate?